# Confused about these pointer reassignment

Tags: c, pointers

Could someone explain what the following code is doing? Especially this structure which appears several times:

```
*ptr1 = (char*)ptr1;
```

The full code:

```
char * buf;

void initialize(int set){
  int j, k;
  char ** ptr1, ** ptr2;
  char * tmp;

  for (j=0; j<ASSOC; j++){
    ptr1 = (char **)&buf[set*LINE_SIZE+j*WAY_SIZE]; // LINE_SIZE=64, WAY_SIZE=256K, ASSOC=16, 15*256K+64
    *ptr1 = (char*)ptr1;
  }

  // permute each set
  for (j=ASSOC-1; j>=1; j--){
    k = rand()%j;
    ptr1 = (char **)&buf[set*LINE_SIZE+j*WAY_SIZE];
    ptr2 = (char **)&buf[set*LINE_SIZE+k*WAY_SIZE];
    tmp = *ptr1;
    *ptr1 = *ptr2;
    *ptr2 = tmp;
  }
}
```

Also, I assume the pointer pointing to buf locations without malloc is a bad practice, so please do not spend time on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*ptr1 = (char*)ptr1;
```

Assigns to the memory location pointed to by ptr its own address.

The whole functions initializes some locations addressed via `buf` to their own respective addresses and then shuffles them around somewhat randomly.